# How to recommend something for the organizers for an exam? (by a student)

Tags: exams, india

I am a student and I want to recommend a change for an exam I am going to *appear for*. So what is the official way to raise a suggestion for the organizers of a particular *exam*?

It is a national level exam which is given for getting admissions into colleges for a bachelor's degree (for engineering). Its given by 230,000 people.

The name of the exam is JEE Advanced.
official website- [jeeadv.ac.in](https://jeeadv.ac.in)

Comment: Please elaborate further. Either you use a non-standard definition of "exam" or there is something else missing. Exams are normally not related to "papers" (i.e., scientific publications) and papers are usually not "organized". Students normally don't "give exams". That's part of a professor's job.

Comment: @Roland In Oxbridge English, "paper" can be an almost-synonym for "exam". (But Oxbridge English is weird).

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure the [tag:india] tag is essential to the question. Likely an answer would apply everywhere.

Comment: @Buffy The "india" tag helps me to understand that "given" here means what I'd express by "taken".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to request a change you need to contact the exam's sponsor/organizer. For something like a national level exam, the contact should be relatively easy to find. In this case it seems to be the Ministry of Education.

But I doubt that much of anything will happen, and certainly not in the short term. National exams take a long time to organize and finalize, they are years-long processes.

However, if the change you wish involves discrimination of some kind, then it might be better to *also* work through the political process, especially if regulations are not being properly observed. Extreme cases might require legal action, which is, itself, both a long and costly process.

Comment: I just want to suggest them a slight change in the interface of the online exam they conduct every year for making it easier to answer questions for the students appearing for that exam. Nothing discriminatory. So I don't think legal action will be required. Thanks.

Comment: @GuyEternal A change in the interface sometimes is discriminatory, therefore it could require legal action. For example, have you included blind person into the consideration?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that it will go against blind people at all (not even remotely).